# Controller Area Network (CAN)

Tags: can-bus

The standard message frame size for CAN is 108-bits (correct me if I am wrong about this... I am still learning about CAN)

Would I be able to send a message that has the sizes of 750 bytes, 2 bytes, or 510 bytes?

Since 108-bits = 13.50 bytes, I assume I could send the 2 bytes message, but how about the other message sizes?

Comment: Do you know the difference between message overhead and data payload? Start there. The frame length is 108 bits, but out of that, the maximum data payload of a CAN frame is 8 bytes. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve, why do you need to send 750 bytes?

Answer (score 2):

CAN is a datalink protocol with a maximum payload of 8 bytes (64 bytes if you are using CAN-FD) per frame.  If you need to send a message larger than that, you will need to make use of a transport protocol to split the message up into individual frames.  Depending on the context, you can create your own ad-hoc protocol to do this, or you may look into a standard protocol such as CANopen or J1939 to provide transport services for you.